# how to use "names" function in lapply

Tags: r, lapply

I encountered a problem seemed easy, but I thought of hard to realize. Here is the question:
I have a list "df", I want to rename its elements with "anm" by using "lapply".
But my fake code cannot realize my intent. 
Could you guys please give me some hints? Tons of thanks.

```
a1 <-   matrix(1:10,5)
a2 <-   matrix(11:20,5)
a3 <-   matrix(21:30,5)
a4 <-   matrix(31:40,5)
df <-   list(a1,a2,a3,a4)
anm <-  c("June","July")   
outvar <-   lapply(df,names) ##fake code
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `colnames` worked instead of `names

```
df = lapply(df, function(x) {colnames(x) = anm; x})
```

Using a loop might even be faster

```
for (i in 1:length(df))
    colnames(df[[i]]) = anm
```

Comment: Great answer. It is my first time to see using "lapply" like your way.

Comment: The first way seems more clear and concise.  Thank you.